# Will it be OK to ferment at a lower ambient temp than yeast recommends?

Tags: fermentation, yeast, fermentation-temperature, sugar

The yeast is Alcotec 24 hour pure original turbo yeast.

I am going to try a sugar wash, so just granulated sugar, water and this yeast(which has added nutrients).

Now the yeast instructions say ideal temps are between 17 and 24 degrees C.

So I am in Scotland and I am going to guess the temp of still water will be around 11-14deg.

I know a couple of degrees can be obtained in the actual fermenting process but will my lower ambient temps compared to the recommend temps basically kill my ferment or will it just be a bit slower?

Comment: Is there no way you can warm it up?

Comment: Well the only way for 26 litres would by an electric blanket. Which I may try .

Comment: Many people do that

Comment: Just as an FYI and not an actual answer: The recommended temperature ranges refer to the temperature of the fermenting wort, not the temperature at the time of yeast pitching (although they are usually the same). 17-24°C should be around room temperature, even in Scotland, so placing the fermenter in an appartement should work.

Answer (score 3):

I think you'll be ok if 11°c is your bottom end.

May be a little slower is all. This turbo yeast is a huge amount of yeast if you use the whole pack in 20L.

These distillers yeasts are pretty resilient. I've even had Super High Gravity Ale yeast from white labs, refuse to stop in 5000ml starter in 38°F fridge.

Answer (score 0):

In general, fermenting low works fine, provided you stay above the point where the yeast goes dormant. Lower fermentation temperatures result in a slower fermentation and a "cleaner" flavour profile (not much of an issue with a sugar wash and turbo yeast).

However, turbo yeast can be a little temperamental. I've gone through a few that got stuck at low temperatures. But because when I ferment a sugar wash for alcohol production in my reflux still I don't worry about bacterial infection, I tend to stick an aquarium heater into the wash in winter to keep it at "turbo" temperatures and I get a quick fermentation.